How to give rest to ones brain during the day?
I often work on/think about some kind of complicated problem until I realize my brain doesn’t yield the mental focus/concentration/working memory needed to make progress any more(, which sometimes happens worrisomely fast). Something I used to do in the past allot at that point, is shift away to some kind of simple entertainment usually some kind of computer game or YouTube video. Rather recently I acknowledged and to some extend experimentally confirmed, that this practice of confronting my already tired brain with a lot of just superficially being processed input might hurt my overall mental capabilities. So I try to avoid that now. However I often wonder, what to do instead in that Situations.
Some things I thought about are:

Meditation seems to have some positive effects, but at least the techniques I had contact with so far seem rather demanding, and I find it hard to motivate myself to them, especially if my brain is already tired. Still, feel free to describe in detail if you know some technique, that you want to share.

Physical workout kinda works, but I already do allot of that in the evenings and I highly prefer being properly warmed up for it, so its not really practical for the purpose.

Sleeping/napping would of course be a trivial way to rest ones brain, but has various problems preventing it from being applied in most of these Situation, which I think I don’t have to describe in detail.


So my question is: What are examples of practical healthy methods executable repeatedly and spontaneously during the day to give ones brain some rest, in between phases of mental exercise?
